# How to conditionally delete records with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following data in my database table

1  myname@email.com  2323
2  myname@email.com  3432
3  myname2@gmail.com 4433

I want to remove all records in table where `email == myname@email.com`

Below is my EJBQL - I do not know where I go wrong, but the query does not work.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ResetPasswordEntity r WHERE r.email=:email");
query.setParameter("email", email);
```

Comment: Are you really using EJB QL? Perhaps you mean JPQL? If so than mind that when using batch delete operations the cascade behavior will not be applied (despite `cascade=DELETE`)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. what is the difference between ejbql and jpql?

Comment: EJB QL is basically coming from the old ages (J2EE) and it was replaced by the JPA QL when the JPA specification was more mature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is correct. I am missing a line of code. Here is it for the benefit for those who might face this issue.

```
query.executeUpdate();
```